# Horizontal image scaling with ScaleTransform in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image

I have an image in a WPF window with the default `Stretch` setting, Uniform, and am making an attempt to make it fill the screen horizontally. I do not wish to use a different `Stretch` setting as this is supposed to a learning experience. The image dimensions being loaded are `420x800`. This is the XAML for the window..

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Background="Red" Height="1200" Width="840">
    <Image Name="Image" Source="{Binding SourceUri}">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="Scale" />
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="Translate" />
            </TransformGroup>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
</Window>
```

On the code-behind, I am attempting to calculate the scaling to zoom the image to fill the horizontal screen and I am using translate transform the move it to the center of the screen. The following bit of code is obviously wrong...

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApplication1 {
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;

            double ImageWidth = 420;

            Scale.ScaleX = Width / ImageWidth;

            Translate.X = -(ImageWidth / 2);
        }

        public string SourceUri {
            get {
                return @"C:\Users\Roel\Desktop\test.png";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am attempting to understand how stretching and transformations are working together but I am having difficulty with this. I would appreciate all insights, even references to detailed explanations, as I have trouble finding any informational source explaining clearly and concisely how the transformations are applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would usually just do this:

```
<Image Name="Image" Source="{Binding SourceUri}" Stretch="Fill"/>
```

---

In case you really need to calculate the stretch transformation manually, you would only need a `ScaleTransform`, no `TranslateTransform`, and you would put that into the [`LayoutTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.layouttransform.aspx) of the Image control. Moreover, the Image control would have to be placed into a Grid, which provides the size of the Windows's "client area". You can't calculate anything based on the Window's Width (or ActualWidth) as that includes the width of the Window's borders.

```
<Grid SizeChanged="Grid_SizeChanged">
    <Image Name="image" Source="{Binding SourceUri}">
        <Image.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="scale"/>
        </Image.LayoutTransform>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

In the Grid's SizeChanged handler you would calculate the scaling as shown below.

```
private void Grid_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    scale.ScaleX = e.NewSize.Width / image.Source.Width;
    scale.ScaleY = e.NewSize.Height / image.Source.Height;
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question, this is supposed to be a learning experience for me, as I intend to proceed with more complex problems using RenderTransform. Changing the transformation to LayoutTransform completely destroys that.

Comment: Then why don't you just start with something more simple, perhaps a fixed size rectangle in the center of a Grid. Then successively apply scaling, translation and perhaps rotation. It's absolutely straightforward.

Comment: You may get a comprehensive explanation of WPF 2-D transforms in this MSDN article: [Transforms Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750596.aspx).